# Is it possible to distort SVG text dynamically?

Tags: html, css, svg

Is it possible to distort SVG text dynamically?

For example, could you apply [filters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/filter) with shifting parameters based on some temporal data?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but you will have to explain better what you're doing in order to get a more useful answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's possible:

```js
let step = () => {
  let blur = document.querySelector('svg > #blur > feGaussianBlur');
  let value = parseFloat(blur.getAttribute('stdDeviation'));
  blur.setAttribute('stdDeviation', value * 1.05);
  
  requestAnimationFrame(step);
};

requestAnimationFrame(step);
```

```html
<svg width="250" height="100"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

  <filter id="blur">
    <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="1"/>
  </filter>

  <text x="15" y="50" font-size="35" filter="url(#blur)">Hello world!</text>
</svg>
```

Probably better to use CSS or SMIL animation though (SMIL snippet provided by [@kaiido](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43269487/is-it-possible-to-distort-svg-text-dynamically/43269622?noredirect=1#comment73609487_43269622)):

```html
<svg width="250" height="100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <filter id="blur">
    <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="0">
      <animate attributeType="XML" attributeName="stdDeviation" from="0" to="5" dur="1s" begin="0s; backward.end + 1s" id="forward" />
      <animate attributeType="XML" attributeName="stdDeviation" from="5" to="0" dur="1s" begin="forward.end" id="backward" />
    </feGaussianBlur>
  </filter>

  <text x="15" y="50" font-size="35" filter="url(#blur)">Hello world!</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: You should at least use an `requestAnimationFrame` loop instead of this setInterval. Here is a SMIL demo : https://jsfiddle.net/x7n7r0Lf/

Comment: @Kaiido The question was: *is it possible?* I limited myself to demonstrating that it's possible, and noted at the end of my answer that it was probably better to use animation. You should turn your fiddle into an answer.

Comment: Nope, it would be the same as yours : "yes it's possible". So I just give this *animation* you talked about in a comment, hoping it to be useful, and also let you know that you should update your js version with an `requestAnimationFrame` loop, since this is the timing function to be used with visual animations.

Comment: This is right inline with what I'm getting at. Cheers!